# "Philippines" vs. "Filipino"

Tags: etymology, orthography

Why is *Filipino* spelled with an *F*? *Philippines* is spelled with a *Ph*. Some have said that it's because in Filipino, *Philippines* starts with *F*; but if this is so, why did we only change the beginning of *Philippines?*

Comment: Probably a "given" but "filipino"=masculine and "filipina"=feminine similar to Spanish.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As this article in the [Spanish Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filipinas) notes:

> El vocablo «Filipinas» deriva del nombre del rey Felipe II de España.

The Philippines were named for King Philip II of Spain. They were «*Las Islas Filipinas*», which was anglicized to the Philippine Islands.

The noun form retains the *F* (*Filipino*), while the adjective form uses *Ph* (*Philippine Embassy*).

(I've seen older texts in British English that referred to the natives as "Philippinos.")

As to why, there's [this answer](http://www.pilipino-express.com/history-a-culture/in-other-words/127-the-basics-of-philippino-filipino.html):

> English never had a suitable equivalent for Filipino – a “Philippine,”
>   “Philippian” or “Philippinian” probably just didn’t sound right, so
>   English adopted the Spanish word *Filipino*, retaining the letter F and
>   the suffix, “ino."

It's interesting to note that the country's official appellation in Pilipino is *Repúblika ng Pilipinas*. The [Pilipino Express](http://www.pilipino-express.com/history-a-culture/in-other-words/127-the-basics-of-philippino-filipino.html) article explains that as well.

Edit: Slate has [another take on Filipino/Philippines](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2006/02/mind_your_ps_and_fs.html), but still doesn't explain the discrepancy in spelling between the noun and adjective forms.

Comment: Good explanation, but it begs the question:  Why the inconsistency in how the noun/adjective forms were anglicized?   Luck of the draw, or was there an actual reason?

Comment: I expanded my answer to try to explain that as well.

Comment: @Lynn: I suspect that someone preferred the look of _Philippine_ to _Filipine_.

Comment: I guess that it's "Philippine/s" and not "Filipine/s" because Felipe in English is Philip, not Filip.